# Solr range faceting on a date field

Tags: solr, solrj, date-range, faceted-search, solr4

I need to apply a range facet to a date field. But the gaps should be in minute intervals, like /10MIN. Solr uses [DateMathParser](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/4_0_0/solr-core/org/apache/solr/util/DateMathParser.html) to parse given gaps and unfortunately it does not support minute intervals (minimum supported time gap is HOUR). Any ideas to handle is issue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My bad, my bad. You can easily use "MINUTE" for a minute range facet. e.g. use "+10MINUTE" for 10 minutes of intervals.